# pytest one time teardown after all tests in all modules have run

Tags: automated-testing, unit-tests, test-strategy, pytest

I have a directory with a bunch of modules. Each module has a bunch of specific tests.

I know how to `teardown` after methods, classes and modules. What am trying to do is `teardown` after all the tests in all the modules in the directory are done running.

My directory structure looks something like this:

[image]

I created this fixture in the `conftest.py`:

```
@pytest.yield_fixture(scope="package")
def **clean_cookie_file**():
  Path.unlink(filename)
```

Implementation of the `fixture` looks like this:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("class_fixture", "**clean_cookie_file**")
class foo(unittest.TestCase):
```

`Expected Result`: file deleted

`Actual Result`: file not deleted

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to make your test classes inherit from a base class with the generic teardown?

Comment: Thank João. My test classes do indeed inherit from the base class. So if I add the tear down logic in the base class, where do I call it from considering that I want to make one teardown call at the end all the tests across all modules.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52873379